# How i get all keys or values with one cookie object?

Tags: c#, linq, cookies

I use cookies to send data to other page.

```
var list = (from d in dc.Admins
                                where d.AdminId == data.UserId
                                select d).FirstOrDefault();
                    // Make object for cookie
                    HttpCookie cAdmin = new HttpCookie("cAdmin");
                    // now add values to cookie cAdmin
                    cAdmin.Values.Add("adminId",list.AdminId.ToString());
                    cAdmin.Values.Add("adminName",list.Name.ToString());
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cAdmin);
                    // you also set expires time
                    //cAdmin.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                    Response.Redirect("~/Admin Folder/MainPageAdmin.aspx");
```

And get values in page named `MainPageAdmin.aspx`.

```
string adminId = Request.Cookies["cAdmin"]["adminId"];
            string adminName = Request.Cookies["cAdmin"]["adminName"];
            lblAdminId.Text = adminId;
            lblAdminName.Text = adminName;
```

Now its only two keys for testing purpose but I want to send full object.
It contain 10 - 15 fields.

I have two question here.

Q1. Can it is possible to add object of LINQ query result to cookie.

For example

```
var list = (from d in dc.Admins
                                where d.AdminId == data.UserId
                                select d).FirstOrDefault();
                    // Make object for cookie
                    HttpCookie cAdmin = new HttpCookie("cAdmin");
                    // now add complete oject to cookie cAdmin
                    cAdmin.Values.Add("admin","list");
```

If yes then how and if no then why?

Q2. If the answer of Q1 is no then can it is possible to access key names with cookie object.

For example

I have cookie object `cAdmin`, I want to access all keys name from this object like `cAdmin.keyname`.

Because to remember all keys name is very difficult. Please help.

Comment: For Q1 I´d recommend write your list to a Json-object and pass it to the cookie.

Comment: @HimBromBeere can you please give some example with code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = (from d in dc.Admins
                            where d.AdminId == data.UserId
                            select d).FirstOrDefault().ToDictionary<TKey,Tvalue>(delegateMethod);

foreach(var entry in list)
{
   cAdmin.Values.Add(entry.Key,entry.Value);
}
```